# Update XML Stored as varchar in a Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I have a table named Schemes which is having `XML` structured file stored as `VARCHAR` in a column.The XML File look like this,

```
<Process> 
<Timers>
<Timer Name="SendNotificationStaffLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="25m" 
NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
<Timer Name="SendNotificationSecretaryLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="600m" 
NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
<Timer Name="ReAssigningRequestToSecretaryLevel1" Type="Interval" 
Value="605m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
<Timer Name="SendNotificationStaffLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="5m" 
NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
<Timer Name="SendNotificationSecretaryLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="10m" 
NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
<Timer Name="ReAssigningRequestToSecretaryLevel2" Type="Interval" 
 Value="12m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
<Timer Name="DeactivateUrlOfFileResubmission" Type="Interval" Value="15m" 
 NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
</Timers>
</process>
```

I need to update the value of each timers by providing the name attribute viz. "SendNotificationStaffLevel1" as parameter for a stored procedure.

I tried

```
update YourTable set
XMLText.modify('replace value of (/Process/Timers/Timer/@Value)[1] with "40m"')
where XMLText.value('(/Process/Timers/Timer/@Value)[1]', 'varchar') = 25m
```

But i need to specify the name attribute for updating the value.How it can be done?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont have control over table contents and data types.It gets auto populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute's filter value to a *predicate* into the `Xpath` like here:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Process>
  <Timers>
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationStaffLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="25m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationSecretaryLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="600m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="ReAssigningRequestToSecretaryLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="605m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationStaffLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="5m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationSecretaryLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="10m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="ReAssigningRequestToSecretaryLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="12m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="DeactivateUrlOfFileResubmission" Type="Interval" Value="15m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
  </Timers>
</Process>';

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)='SendNotificationStaffLevel1';
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Process/Timers/Timer[@Name=sql:variable("@Name")]/@Value)[1] with "40m"'); 

SELECT @xml;
```

You can read the `Xpath` as:

- Start at `<Process>`
- Dive deeper into `<Timers>`, then to `<Timer>`
- Find the first (`[1]`) occurance where the attribute name is like the external variable
- Change the attribute `@Value`

### With table data

You can easily adapt the above to work against a table's column, but:

If the XML is saved as `VARCHAR(x)` you must trick it out. `.modify()` needs the native XML type and you cannot update a casted column. I'd suggest to write an intermediate table, do the update there and write it back:

A *mockup table*:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXmlAsString VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
('<Process>
  <Timers>
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationStaffLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="25m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationSecretaryLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="600m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="ReAssigningRequestToSecretaryLevel1" Type="Interval" Value="605m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationStaffLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="5m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="SendNotificationSecretaryLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="10m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="ReAssigningRequestToSecretaryLevel2" Type="Interval" Value="12m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
    <Timer Name="DeactivateUrlOfFileResubmission" Type="Interval" Value="15m" NotOverrideIfExists="true" />
  </Timers>
</Process>');
```

--Write the casted column to a temp table

```
SELECT ID
      ,YourXmlAsString --<-- You don't need this actually
      ,CAST(YourXmlAsString AS XML) YourXmlAsXml
INTO #tmpTable
FROM @mockup ;
```

--Do the update

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)='SendNotificationStaffLevel1';
UPDATE #tmpTable
SET YourXmlAsXml .modify('replace value of (/Process/Timers/Timer[@Name=sql:variable("@Name")]/@Value)[1] with "40m"');
```

--Update the original table

```
UPDATE t
SET YourXmlAsString=CAST(tmp.YourXmlAsXml AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM #tmpTable tmp
INNER JOIN @mockup t ON tmp.ID=t.ID;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @mockup;
```

### Hint:

If there is any chance to change the column's type to XML you really should do this...

Answer (score 0):

The examples I find do it a bit differently

```
UPDATE HR_XML
SET Salaries.modify('replace value of 
(/Salaries/Marketing/Employee[@ID=("2")]/Salary/text())[1] with ("60000")')
GO
```

For your case it would be I guess

```
update YourTable set
XMLText.modify('replace value of 
(/Process/Timers/Timer[@Name=("SendNotificationSecretaryLevel2")]/@Value)[1] with "40m"')
GO
```

I'm not sure about the where part of your update though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer